# Configuring NGINX to Retry idempotent Failed Requests on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I configure NGINX to retry idempotent failed requests on a Spring Boot app deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk running Corretto 11 on 64-bit Amazon Linux 2?

If it is impossible to handle this with Nginx, can I handle it in the application?